# Feature engineering gaussian distributed input

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am designing a NN classifier where most of the input features are estimations of gaussian distributions. I.e. one feature has a mu and a sigma value.

- The classifier has about 30 input features, 60 if you consider each mu and sigma their own feature.
- The number of outputs are 15, i.e. there are 15 possible classifications.
- I have about 50k examples to use for training/verification.

I can think of a few different scenarios of how to transform these features into something useful but I am not clever enough to come to any conclusions on how they would impact my results.

First scenario is to just scale and blindly pass each mu and sigma individually. I don't really see how sigma would help the classifier in this case, since it's just a measure of uncertainty. Optimally this would lead to slightly "fuzzier" classifications which possibly could be used for estimating some certainty metric of a classification result.

Second scenario is to generate more test cases by drawing a value from the gaussian of each each of the 30 input features, and then normalizing these random values. This would give me more training data, which could be useful.

As I side note I have the possibility to get more data (about 50k examples more) but I am not sure how accurate that data is so I would like to try with this smaller set first to see if it converges.

The question is: Is there any consensus or interesting paper in the community, describing how to deal with estimated uncertainty in input features?

Thanks!

P.S. Sorry for my bad wording, ML is not my professional domain nor is English my native language.

Comment: It's not really a neural network, but rather a very well known approach to control problems, but perhaps you would find some useful concepts in how the Kalman Filter works.

Comment: You know what a kalman filter is, o just don't see how it fits my problem description. Couldnt you eöaborate @maciek?

Comment: It's true that it is rather a loose comment. I meant only one aspect of the issue you described, namely sigmas. I thought that seeing how Kalman deals with them might help you come up with some new idea. But I didn't mean to address here your question about populating test cases.

Comment: I see. The values actually already come from something very similar to a calman filter, and the sigmas are used to represent the accuracy of the estimation.

Comment: What I ended up doing right now was to draw random training samples using the normal distributions, in this way I ended up with 20x more training data. We'll see how this works out :)